# Laravel - Set a session/cookie on click of element to persist toggle state

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have a link and a css hidden div:

```
<a href="#" class="bio-toggler">Click me</a>
<div class="bio">Your bio</div>
```

When I click the link, it shows the div. Refresh the page, and it's hidden again. I want the 'bio' div to stay open even when refreshing the page if the link was clicked and the div shown. I also want the opposite, that if I clicked the link again and the 'bio' div get hidden, to stay hidden on page refresh.

Basically, I am trying to "persist" the toggle state of the div in Laravel, and not sure how to do it.

I am using jquery for the show/hide functionality.

```
$('.bio-toggler').click(function(){
    $('.bio').toggle();
});
```

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do an AJAX POST to an endpoint within your application which sets the variable. When you're showing you're HTML, just check for that.

jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'http://localhost:8000/api/profile/toggle',
  success: function() {}
});
```

Controller:

```
public function toggle()
{
   Session::set('toggled', true);
}
```

View:

```
@if (Session::get('toggled'))
    <a href="#" class="bio-toggler">Click me</a>
    <div class="bio">Your bio</div>
@endif
```

This is just boilerplate. You would probably have to tune it, like check if there is an older value to toggle in PHP, etc.